# ¿Como hago para que mi menú en Bootstrap 4 se desplace con la pagina, que quede fijo en la parte superior?

Tags: bootstrap, menú, bootstrap-4, navegador-web, nav

Un gran saludo.

Tengo una dificultad, ya cree, mi menú en Bootstrap 4, sin embargo ahora deseo que quede fijo, que se desplace con la pagina web,y no he logrado encontrar la forma de hacerlo`introducir el código aquí`, puesto que ya lo cree.

Gracias, les comparto.

```css
/*MENU*/

.topnav {
    background-color: #E4276B;
    overflow: hidden;

}
#maint {
    font-family: "satisfy";
    font-size: 2.2vw;
    font-size: 2.2vh;
    
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #FFD614;
    color: black;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4A80BC;
    color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
   <!--Javascript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
       
    
</head>
<body>
    

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a href="inicio.html" class="active"> <div id ="maint"> Nueva Forma</div></a>
<a href="acerca.html">Acerca de mí</a>
<a href="acerca.html">Portafolio</a>
<a href="acerca.html">Contacto</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Estas usando los estilos y el diseño de bootstrap ? tal parece que no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes agregar un `position: fixed` a tu nabvar, de esta manera:

```css
/*MENU*/

.topnav {
    background-color: #E4276B;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*aqui esta el cambio*/
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*fin del cambio*/
}
#maint {
    font-family: "satisfy";
    font-size: 2.2vw;
    font-size: 2.2vh;
    
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #FFD614;
    color: black;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4A80BC;
    color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imagenes/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
   <!--Javascript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
       
    
</head>
<body>
    

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="inicio.html" class="active"> <div id ="maint"> Nueva Forma</div></a>
  <a href="acerca.html">Acerca de mí</a>
  <a href="acerca.html">Portafolio</a>
  <a href="acerca.html">Contacto</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, quos, nulla. Sapiente fuga mollitia non minima odit doloribus natus asperiores quam id. Maiores velit, possimus magnam sint deleniti ad molestiae.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, quos, nulla. Sapiente fuga mollitia non minima odit doloribus natus asperiores quam id. Maiores velit, possimus magnam sint deleniti ad molestiae.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, quos, nulla. Sapiente fuga mollitia non minima odit doloribus natus asperiores quam id. Maiores velit, possimus magnam sint deleniti ad molestiae.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, quos, nulla. Sapiente fuga mollitia non minima odit doloribus natus asperiores quam id. Maiores velit, possimus magnam sint deleniti ad molestiae.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, quos, nulla. Sapiente fuga mollitia non minima odit doloribus natus asperiores quam id. Maiores velit, possimus magnam sint deleniti ad molestiae.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, quos, nulla. Sapiente fuga mollitia non minima odit doloribus natus asperiores quam id. Maiores velit, possimus magnam sint deleniti ad molestiae.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil, quos, nulla. Sapiente fuga mollitia non minima odit doloribus natus asperiores quam id. Maiores velit, possimus magnam sint deleniti ad molestiae.</p>
  
  
 </body>
</html>
```